# Check Default Shipping Address Checkbox

Tags: workflow, netsuite

We have a form that is submitted using the online forms, however it does not set the "default shipping address" checkbox.  I have tried to pick up this field by workflow but i cannot see this anywhere.

Ideally i would have it auto set on the address for any new record submitted from online. Am i chasing the impossible?  It seems that none of the sub record/sublist address fields for a customer are evaluable via a workflow.